# Passing req.user (PassportJS variables) to other modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Currently using Node, Express & Passport to make an app. I'm using the local strategy for Passport and all authentication works so far. I can retrieve my `req.user` variable when logged in. (Apologies in advance, just learning and getting used to Node)

My question is, how do I pass this variable to other modules in my project? For example:

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var assert = require('assert');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

...

require('./routes')(app); //where my authentication is done

var server = http.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:80');
});

var socketjs = require('./lib/socket.js');
socketjs.listen(server); //where I want to pass my logged in user info
```

Should I make a function to pull user information and make a call to that instead within `socket.js` ? If so, how would you suggest me structuring that? I would prefer to not expose any user data as a cookie on the client side.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `req.user` is only available *inside* the routes, where the request object is exposed

Comment: How would I be able to pass it over to other modules? Do I have to include them in routes?

Comment: Taking a look at passport.socketio, might be what I need.